# Mysql where search using renamed column

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, where-clause

I am trying to do a search and sort query on a left join like this:

**QUERY**

```
SELECT 
IFNULL(TABLE1.NAME, TABLE2.NAME) AS NAME 
FROM TABLE1 LEFT JOIN TABLE2 ON ...
WHERE NAME LIKE "%QUERY%"
ORDER BY NAME ASC;
```

The problem is that the server returns error `Unknown column 'NAME'`, but if I remove the where clause, order by clause works fine. On the other hand if I change the where clause to

`WHERE IFNULL(TABLE1.NAME, TABLE2.NAME) LIKE "%QUERY%"`

then query works. But it brings a bit of mess in code and I would prefer using renamed column name in where clause. Maybe I'm missing something or is it impossible to use a renamed column in where clause?

Comment: Are you using SQL Server or MySQL?

Comment: MySQL server version 5.5.29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL does not allow using column aliases defined in the `SELECT` in the `WHERE` clause.  This is because the `WHERE` clause is logically parsed before the `SELECT`.

The normal SQL solution to this problem is to use a subquery:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT IFNULL(TABLE1.NAME, TABLE2.NAME) AS NAME 
      FROM TABLE1 LEFT JOIN TABLE2 ON ...
     ) t
WHERE NAME LIKE '%QUERY%'
ORDER BY NAME ASC;
```

Although this works on all databases, it is not a good solution for MySQL for two reasons.  First, the subquery is materialized, which incurs an overhead.  Second, the query cannot go into a view.  Instead, MySQL extends the `HAVING` clause, so you can do:

```
SELECT IFNULL(TABLE1.NAME, TABLE2.NAME) AS NAME 
FROM TABLE1 LEFT JOIN TABLE2 ON ...
HAVING NAME LIKE '%QUERY%'
ORDER BY NAME ASC;
```

Also, you should get in the habit of only using single quotes for string and date constants, and then always using them in that case.

Comment: I have tried the having solution and it works. That's good news for me :) Thank you. Also I'll have to take a look about the having clause in detail, haven't used it before